# How to make a oval shape for launcher 3's Hotseat dock

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hello I am trying to make a oval dock as seen here:

[image]

Here's the code for  hotseat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.android.launcher3.Hotseat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.android.launcher3.CellLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:background="@drawable/dock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        launcher:containerType="hotseat" />
</com.android.launcher3.Hotseat>
```

EDIT here is my updated dock.xml shape code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>

    <solid android:color="#ffff" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="270dp" />

</shape>
```

However when I run the app the dock looks like this:

[image]

Any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

After setting margin of 5dp and removing size in dock shape:

[image]

EDIT 2:

After setting margin of 16dp:

[image]

Comment: In corner, keep only radius or all of 4 corner specific radius, but not both. Also don't set the size in the shape of your dock because the size should be set in the layout you are using it. Post your layout which is using your dock drawable

Comment: it might be something alike `<corners android:radius="8dp"/>` ...

Comment: @MarcEstrada I've added the layout in which i'm using the drawable please see the edited post under the hotseat.xml code

Comment: So do all I said in first comment, and then set the a margin in your `<com.android.launcher3.CellLayout>` and post the result.

Comment: @MarcEstrada i changed the dock.xml code please see edit in the post but what am I looking  for to change in the com.android.launcher3.CellLayout class? Please let me know and thank you for all your help so far :)

Comment: I answered because code looks better if it's formatted. Try what I said, and if it's not working, post your image result and provide also your CellLayout filling.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the size in the `shape`, since you'll set the size in your `hotseat` (via wrap_content or match_parent).

So change your dock as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners android:radius="8dp"/>

<solid android:color="#ffff" />

<padding
    android:bottom="0dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="0dp" />

</shape>
```

Then, in your `hotseat` set a margin, for example 5dp (change this value as you need):

```
<com.android.launcher3.Hotseat
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

   <com.android.launcher3.CellLayout
       android:id="@+id/layout"
       android:background="@drawable/dock"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       launcher:containerType="hotseat" />
   </com.android.launcher3.Hotseat>
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it now looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o6qhYJGQ4R158dbfCiYGSE7G9mF7Kt_p/view?usp=sharing please let me know what else i shout try :)

Comment: Thats better than you had yesterday :) let me  arrive at home and I'll help you

Comment: I need to know how are you inflating the icons and how are you populating the dock. Let me know please. Also, make the margin bigger, for example 16dp, to test if it's working properly. @Phoneswapshop

Comment: here is what the dock looks like with a margin of 16dp: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0GHlGFNk1eSeGZxdGNhczhCUjA2eE93NXc0eE5vTUsxUnV3

Comment: Wow, only changing the margin? So weird. Post the code you are using to inflate the incons and how are you populating the dock, please. This big white space should not be there.

Comment: Tell me you what class is that shows these views :) I don't know your code

Comment: Did you advanced with this question? @Phoneswapshop